# A condition for two linear operators to commute

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $V$ be finite dimensional and suppose $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$, consisting of vectors that are eigenvectors of both $T$ and $S$, linear operators on $V$.

I've read that as a result $TS=ST$, but I really don't see why this is true.

How do you prove this?

Comment: Try expanding $TSv$ and $STv$ for any vector $v\in V$.

Comment: @CheeHan Right, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ are eigenvectors of both $T$ and $S$, there exists scalars $\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\}$ and $\{\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n\}$ such that
$$Tv_j = \alpha_jv_j \ \ \textrm{ and } \ \ Sv_j = \beta_jv_j \ \ \textrm{ for each }j=1,\ldots,n.$$
Next, choose any vector $v\in V$, then $v$ has a unique representation
$$ v = \sum_{j=1}^n \gamma_jv_j. $$
We now expand $TSv$, where we crucially use the assumption that both $T,S$ are linear operators: 
\begin{align*}
TSv = T(Sv) & = TS\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \gamma_jv_j\right) \\
& = T\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\gamma_j Sv_j\right) \\
& = \sum_{j=1}^n \gamma_j T(Sv_j) \\
& = \sum_{j=1}^n \gamma_j T(\beta_jv_j) \\
& = \sum_{j=1}^n \gamma_j\beta_j Tv_j \\
& = \sum_{j=1}^n \gamma_j\beta_j\alpha_jv_j
\end{align*}
A similar calculation shows that
$$ STv = S(Tv) = \sum_{j=1}^n \gamma_j\alpha_j\beta_jv_j = \sum_{j=1}^n \gamma_j\beta_j\alpha_jv_j = TSv. $$
The desired claim follows since $v\in V$ was arbitrary.